# MATLAB - Assignment has fewer non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Tags: arrays, matlab

I set up an array like this.

```
img = % A GRAY-SCALE IMAGE
r = 20;
corners = randi( [1080, 1020], 100, 2);
d = r * 2 + 1;
squares = zeros(size(corners, 1), d, d);
w = corners(:, 1);
h = corners(:, 2);
for i = 1:size(corners, 1)
    sq = img(max(w(i) - r, 0) : min(w(i) + r, size(img, 1)), ...
        max(h(i) - r, 0) : min(h(i) + r, size(img, 2)));
    squares(i, :, :) = (sq - mean(sq(:))) / std(sq(:));
end
```

When I try to run this code, I get an error message saying "Assignment has fewer non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts". I'm not sure what this means because when I print out `size(squares(i, :, :))` and `size(sq)` I get `1 41 41` and `41 41` respectively. I'm not sure what's wrong or how to fix it. Help?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the *full* error message.

Comment: Not sure. But I think you want to use **`squares(:, :,i)`**, instead of **`squares(i,:,:)`**

Comment: I used `squeeze` and it worked.